# Перевод в пользователя в другое состояние aiogramm

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, aiogram

Можно ли как-то перевести пользователя в другое состояние после перезапуска бота, что бы пользователь ничего не писал боту ?

Comment: Что значит "другое состояние"? Забанить пользователя что ли?

Comment: @andreymal, в aiogram есть машина состояний, почитайте про нее.